# Big difference in performance using OpenVINO model on CPU vs Intel Compute Stick 2

Tags: intel, openvino

I own an Intel Compute Stick 2 that I intend to use to process object detection networks.

After installing OpenVINO on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04), I tried running the object detection python demo on a video. When running it on the Intel stick, I would get a speed of around 7.5 frames per second, while running it on my laptop Intel CPU is a lot faster at 44 frames per second.

Even if my laptop is a decent gaming laptop, I was surprised by the fact that processing on the Intel stick is so much slower. I plan to use the Intel stick on another device, not my laptop, but I would like to understand why there is this big difference in performance. Anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: I actually just bought a OpenCV Camera OAK-D with Intel MyraidX, I ran my model on both the camera and CPU, the CPU is running much faster than the MyraidX even after optimized model(the .blob model)

Comment: That's exactly my experience as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an expected performance of Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2.

Check out the following discussions regarding the performance of Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2.

[Raspberry Pi and Movidius NCS Face Recognition](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/01/06/raspberry-pi-and-movidius-ncs-face-recognition/)

[Share | Intel Neural Compute Stick 2 (Intel Neural Compute Stick 2) related tests](https://www.programmersought.com/article/88685697672/)

[Battle of Edge AI — Nvidia vs Google vs Intel](https://soon-yau.medium.com/battle-of-edge-ai-nvidia-vs-google-vs-intel-8a3b87243028)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looking at the links you provided it makes sense, I guess I was expecting the NCS 2 to be faster than it actually is